# How to create a generic function that returns the generic type in C#

Tags: c#, generics

Trying to create a generic lerp function in C#. My function currently looks like the one below.

```
public T Lerp<T>(T lhs, T rhs, float t)
{
    return (1.0f - t) * lhs + t * rhs;
}
```

The question referenced as a duplicate constrains they type to built in types. I don't want to return a constraint I want to return an object of type T(Generic Object?) in C#.

Comment: Why `ref`? Doesn't look like you're changing the arguments within the method.

Comment: @MainMa: was following a tutorial that did it that way. it wasn't necessary i just had it as such.
I didn't see what the difference was between asking here or there. I guess SO would be more applicable.

Answer (score 3):

To do this requires a couple steps.  We'll remove the ref keywords because they don't help in this case.  Let's assume you wanted to LERP vectors.  Let's also assume you have a set of vector objects called Vector2, Vector3, and Vector4 (for a 2 dimensional vector, 3d, and 4d respectively).  To make the Lerp function work with all three of them, you have to adjust those objects first.

Create a base class for all three that performs the multiplication between a vector and a floating point number.  The base class calls an abstract method that performs the actual math in the specific vector objects.  The base class would look something like this:

```
public abstract BaseVector
{
    public abstract BaseVector Multiply(float multiplier);

    public static BaseVector operator *(BaseVector v, float multiplier)
    {
        return v.Multiply(multiplier);
    }

    // Add the operator * overload where the multiplier is first
}
```

Now, for the function itself, it's a matter of providing a `where` clause to make use of the behavior of the base class.  If your Vector2, Vector3, and Vector4 classes all extend BaseVector and implement the Multiply() method, then this will work:

```
public T Lerp<T>(T lhs, T rhs, float t)
    where T : BaseVector
{
    return (1.0f - t) * lhs + t * rhs;
}
```

It's not going to be able to get more generic than that because operator overloads are static extension methods that have to be declared in the class that they apply to.  You would be able to use an interface and then any object that implements that interface would be able to be used, but you would have to call the Multiply method declared in the interface directly.  In that case, you would change the `where` clause to have T implement the interface.  It's the same syntax, just that the type changes from `BaseVector` to the interface name.

You won't be able to call method names on the object that don't exist in the base `Object` type unless you specify the where clause.

---

Answer from programmers.stackexchange.com:

If your intent is to figure out how to implement the [LERP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerp_%28computing%29) function with any passed in type, then your question is probably more appropriate for Stackoverflow.com.

Since linear interpolation is usually implemented with floating point numbers, it's probably most clean *not* to use a generic for this case.  The result is a floating point number:

```
// Precise method which guarantees v = v1 when t = 1.
public static float Lerp(float v0, float v1, float t)
{
    return (1-t)*v0 + t*v1;
}
```

You might increase the precision if you think it would be useful by changing all the types to a double.  This keeps a simple function operating simply.  The problem you'll run into is that operator overloading is static, so if you want to create a function that operates on a number of objects (for example vectors) you'll have to create a base class that all those objects extend which defines the `operator*` overload and provide a where clause to restrict `T` to something that extends that base class.  That can get complicated.

The point of this answer is to get you to think about why you feel you:

1. Need the function to be generic
2. Need the `ref` keyword

Both are complicating a pretty simple function.  The `ref` keyword is unnecessary because you are only reading the parameters.  The generic is unnecessary when you are working with numerical values because they all have implicit conversion operators when you are increasing precision.  They also all have explicit conversion operators when you are decreasing precision.  In short, unless you are working with a complex type, keep the method very simple and only break out the more complicated tricks when you really need it.

Comment: I wanted to learn more about how to do it in the language. The question is mostly for education purposes. The ref keyword was just included because i pulled it from a tutorial their isn't a good reason why I included them in my example.